# Running ssh-agent in bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have created file ssh-start.sh which contains:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I'm running it and have output:

```
Agent pid 1234
Identity added: ~/.ssh/id_rsa (~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

but when I run

```
ssh-add -l
```

I'm getting:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix that?

(when I run commands from ssh-start.sh file directly in terminal it works fine)

Comment: Is the last command i.e., `ssh-add -l` part of the script or you're running it after the script runs?

Comment: I'm running it after script runs. If I add it to script it show my identity, but run 5 seconds later from shell doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh` command needs to know how to talk to the `ssh-agent`. They know that from the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.

```
[gc@slave4 ~]$ ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ln4RuPajkE2A/agent.11091; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=11092; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 11092;
```

If you run `ssh-add -l` *after* the script, neither `ssh` nor `ssh-add` will be able to see that the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is set. So run all commands as part of a script or all from the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for thank hint, that pointed me to right direction, now I know I need to run my script using "source" command: "source ./ssh-start.sh" (or use "." instead of "source" to make it shorter).

Comment: Yes, running in the same shell is the key whether you source it or keep everything in the script. I'm glad it helped. :)

Comment: @Technext Spent half a day solving this issue) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. :)