# Gitlab CI - Setup SSH Key In Bash

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci

I followed gitlab's documentation on [SSH keys when using the Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html) to setup connection to my remote server, which works as expected.

```
before_script:
  - which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

However, I'd like to put those commands in a separate script like this:

```
before_script:
  - bash ./scripts/ssh-config.sh
```

ssh-config.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add <(echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY)
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
```

When trying to connect to the remote server, it gives the following error:

```
$ bash scripts/ssh-config.sh
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
Agent pid 15
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (/dev/fd/63)
$ ssh op@example.com "touch test"
Warning: Permanently added 'example.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.    
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

The script seemed to have been executed correctly and have output the same logs as that by the previous method. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect it's to do with the fact you're running in a subshell the second way. After the script exits, ssh-agent probably does too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running ssh-add either use source or . so that the script runs within the same shell, if you don't the ssh-agent in your current shell will not have the new key. So in your case you would do the following.

```
before_script:
  - . ./scripts/ssh-config.sh
```

or

```
before_script:
  - source ./scripts/ssh-config.sh
```

Adapted answer from a similar question that was poorly worded. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46041447/8554496) is the original.

**NOTE:** There's no need for `bash` because you are already using `#!/bin/bash` within your script